# psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: postgresql, psql

`pgpass.conf` is placed on path `%APPDATA%roaming/pgadmin/pgpass.conf` .

but it is continuously giving an Error-

> **psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied**

might be stupid but one more Question is there when to use pg_hba.conf and when to use pgpass.conf file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the batch script declared system variable `$PGPASSWORD` with the password string instead of using pgpass.conf file.

Doc - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html

Also found issue with `pgpass.conf` file needs to put it to PostgreSQL server and not with pgAdmin (client's dir).